# ASP.net repeater to display properly formatted images and text

Tags: asp.net, css, image, formatting, repeater

This is sort of a general web development question that I need some experts' advice on.  This is probably quite a no brainer for some of you, but I am having trouble getting this to display properly.

I have a database table set up where each entry has 5 text fields, and one image.  What I want to do is use the repeater to display the text on the left hand side of the div, and the image on the right hand side of the div (basically aligned with the center of the text).

```
Company Name
Description1
Description2
Description3                                       Image goes about here.
Description4
Description5
```

I have the repeater all configured properly and ready to go, it's displaying the text just fine in a well formatted way.  However, I'm having trouble getting that image to display properly.  Do I need to use text wrapping here to accomplish this?  I'm pretty stuck and don't know where to proceed.  I can post my ASP.net code here if desired.

Thank you so much in advance.  Very helpful site for new programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you can't set a fixed height on your column divs? Is so, and if you're happy to use an HTML `table` (many aren't) then your life will be much simpler than trying to vertically align an image inside a floated div using CSS. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:960px; margin:auto 0;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:75%;">
            <asp:repeater...>
            </asp:repeater>
        </td>
        <td style="width:25%;" valign="middle">
            <asp:Image .../>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notice the `valign="middle"` attribute on the right `td`. Although `valign` is deprecated in HTML5, it still works in all modern browsers and all supported versions of IE.

NOTE: many will argue that tables aren't SEO friendly or that tables aren't intended for this, plus it's not strictly html5 compliant, so you'll need to way that up. Personally, because it just works and solves a simple problem that CSS can't without silly hacks, I'd use it without worrying too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the div with the text inside to the left and the image to the right, you can use "Float: Left" to the div with the text inside and "float:right" to the div of the image. This should look like this :

```
<div style="float: left;"> <--- float:left
   <table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="TournoiAvenirRep" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <tr>
                <td>...</td>
             </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
   </table>
</div>

<div style="float:right"> <--- float:right
  <img  src='...' />
</div>
```

And if you want to have an other div BUT not on the same line , you must add a "clear:both" to the new div :

```
<div style="float: left;"> 
   <table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="TournoiAvenirRep" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <tr>
                <td>...</td>
             </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
   </table>
</div>

<div style="float:right">
  <img  src='...' />
</div>

<div style="clear:both"> <------ here clear both
   ...
</div>
```

Hope this will help you ! , vinc

EDIT : If you want learn more about css positioning and float you can go to [W3 school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp), they have some nice tuto about it.

Answer (score -2):

This is a CSS issue. You'll need two floated divs, something like this:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div style="float:left; width:75%;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" [etc] />
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; width:25%;">
        <asp:Image ID="MyImage" runat="server" [etc] />
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want specific examples, please see http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/.

Comment: Will this vertically centre the image?

Comment: With the right styles, yes. Just Google "css vertically center image" and you should be able to find what you need.

Comment: Can you post a working solution here then? That's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Alas, the OP's employer doesn't pay me. I edited my answer to link to a page where there are several different methods to try.